# No persister For: Error while Saving data using fluent hibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-5, fluent-nhibernate

i am trying to save data into my DB table using fluent hibernate but its giving me "No persister for:". i tried many solutions available on net but nothing help me to get out from this situation. Can any one help me to resolve i spend almost 2 days to find the reason of this error but still not found.

```
private static ISessionFactory InitializeSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012

   .ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"]
   .ConnectionString).ShowSql())
   .Mappings(m =>
    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Domain.Mapping.StatusMap>())
   .BuildSessionFactory();
}

public class StatusTypeTest
{
    public double Statusid { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double? Createbyid { get; set; }

}

public class StatusMap : ClassMapping<StatusTypeTest>
{
    public StatusMap()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("Status");
        Lazy(false);
        Id(x => x.Statusid, map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));

        Property(x => x.Title, map => map.Length(50));
        Property(x => x.Description, map => map.Length(250));
        Property(x => x.Createbyid, map => map.Precision(10));
    }
}



 StatusTypeTest obj= new StatusTypeTest(); 
 obj.Title = "test";
 obj.description = "My unit test";
 obj.createdBy = 1; 

 using (var session = Factory.OpenSession()) 
 { 
   using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    { 
      session.Save(obj);
      transaction.Commit(); 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: then check if `StatusMap` constructor is called (place a breakpoint)

Comment: no its not calling

Comment: then you need to find out why it is not calling. check if `InitializeSessionFactory` is called

Answer (score 0):

g. you could register below class as singleton

```
    public class SessionSource
    {
        private string _connectionStringProvider;
        public SessionSource(string connectionStringProvider)
        {
            _connectionStringProvider = connectionStringProvider;
        }

        public ISession GetSession()
        {
                var session = GetSessionFactory().OpenSession();
                return session;
        }

        private Configuration AssembleConfiguration(string connectionString)
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                    .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MappingCandidate>())
                    .Database(() =>
                    {
                        return FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration
                            .MsSql2012
                            .ConnectionString(connectionString);
                    })
                    .BuildConfiguration();
        }

        private ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
        {
            var sessionFactory = AssembleConfiguration(_connectionStringProvider).BuildSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

and then like you used Factory.OpenSession() you can inject sessionSource and use it

```
 using (var session = _sessionSource.GetSession())
 {
```

with this you can be sure that you have register all required mappings.